# Can I enter the debugger by sending an interrupt/signal?

Tags: matlab, debugging

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> interrupts a program.  If I have `dbstop on error` set to true, this will put me in the debugger, because an interruption is treated as an error.  However, the program is still interrupted; I can not continue it.

If I have a Matlab program running, is it possible *after it has started* to enter the debugger without triggering an error?  To achieve the effect that a breakpoint would normally have, so either to add a breakpoint for an already running program, or tell it 'break wherever you are right now'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily..

As suggested in the answer for the question that was linked as a dup, you can create certain conditions outside the MATLAB environment that the MATLAB code can check for. Since MATLAB is more or less single threaded, it makes doing things like that reallly challenging.

**The Better Way:** (I think/Hope)

I have not tried this yet, but I am almost positive you are able to edit uicontrols even while code is running because that IS on a different "thread" of sorts. For example, you can check a checkbox even while your code is running. If you were to include in your code something that checks for this checkbox value to be a 1, and if it is a 1, enter debug mode, I think that would work for you.

The good things about this is that everything stays in MATLAB and you don't need to do things like create a file to debug. The bad thing is you still need to add extra code to check which sometimes isn't feasible.

Hope this will work for you.